# shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation disabled after UIImagePickercontroller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, orientation, uiimagepickercontroller

I've got a particular issue at the moment concerning shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation on iOS 5. To put it simply, my whole project is supposed to handle Portrait only, except for the image viewer which should handle UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown.

Basically, I put this code in all of my viewControllers :

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation*)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

Then, I've got a ViewController called PageViewController. There is a button there that invokes an UIImapgePickercontroller. And once the image is picked, I dismissViewController (the imagePicker), so I get back to PageViewController and I push forward the ImageViewController.

Which gives :

```
                3
```

PageViewController   ->   ImageViewController

```
   1 |   A  2
     V   |
```

Thanks for you help.

ImagePickerController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the answer was laid somewhere else.
In my PageViewController, I'm using a `UIPageViewController`. So when I take a picture, I turn a page and add the picture to that other page using `setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion`. However, I presented the ImageViewController right after calling `setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion` and not using the completion block. So I just moved my `presentViewController:animated:completion:` in the completion block and it worked just fine.

example here :

```
[self.pageController setViewControllers:controllersArray direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:^(BOOL finished) {
   if (finished)
      [self presentViewController:imageController animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Hope this will help someone else.